# http://sub.site.com is incorrectly redirecting to http://www.sub.site.com instead of https://sub.site.com

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, redirect, subdomain

Using Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04.2

I have blog.ryangiglio.com set up as a virtualhost. I used the letsencrypt certbot to generate an SSL cert for the server, and set it to force redirects from http://blog.ryangiglio.com to https://blog.ryangiglio.com. When you go directly to https://blog.ryangiglio.com, everything works fine. But if you go to http://blog.ryangiglio.com instead, you get redirected to http://www.blog.ryangiglio.com which doesn't and shouldn't exist.

There is no .htaccess file in the webroot for this domain that could be causing a conflict.

Here is the blog.ryangiglio.com.conf config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName blog.ryangiglio.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/error.log
    # CustomLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/access.log combined

  <Directory /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =blog.ryangiglio.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And the blog.ryangiglio.com-le-ssl.conf file generated by certbot

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName blog.ryangiglio.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/error.log
    # CustomLog /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/access.log combined

  <Directory /var/www/blog.ryangiglio.com/public_html/>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.ryangiglio.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/blog.ryangiglio.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
</IfModule>
```

I don't see anything in either of these files that could be causing the error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Permanent redirects are cached by your browser, so often changed configurations settings won't get picked up, unless you clear those caches or test from a private browser session. Also the apache httpd project recommendation is to [avoid mod_rewrite for simple redirects](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) from http to https. - Regardless you might want to check the output of `apache2ctl -S` or `httpd -S`

Comment: It's not cached, it's definitely still happening. However it only seems to happen in Safari and Firefox, and only if you've never been to the https version. What can I learn from the output of apache2ctl -S? It's telling me that there are vhosts for blog.ryangiglio.com on both port 80 and 443 and which .conf they're using but that's all